# Como aumentar largura do popup modal no mobile

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde, criei um botão que abre um modal no bostrap, dentro dele inseri algumas tabelas. No desktop funciona perfeitamente, porém no mobile uma das tabelas "estoura o modal". Gostaria de saber como alterar a largura do modal no mobile.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Página em questão:http://tratspay.com/app/saque.html#

Comment: Acho que o problema não é o modal, sim a tabela. Acho que você pode esconder algumas colunas no mobile, ou criar uma outra formatação de tabela, ou utilizar o .table-responsive do bootstrap

Comment: Obrigado, Zaffar! Consegui solucionar o bug adicionando o comando table responsive. Valeu pela força!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha a própria documentação do Bootstrap indica como fazer a tabela responsiva. Não sei se fica ao seu gosto, mas é o que indica a documentação oficial, frameworks são assim... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

O que vc deve fazer é colocar a classe `.table-responsive` na `col-` que precede a table, como abaixo

```
<div class="col-sm-12 divContas table-responsive">
```

Dessa forma vc vai ter o resultado da imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui arrumar fazendo exatamente isso. Obrigado pela força!

Comment: @IgorRosa sem problemas meu caro!

Comment: Estou conseguindo deixar o meu site lindão com ajuda de vocês do fórum. Tô felizão kk